# Include filename and path in external location when creating a table in Trino

Tags: sql, amazon-s3, hive, create-table, trino

I have a S3 bucket named `test-bucket` with the following structure

```
- test-bucket 
  - surveys
    - abc.json
    - def.json
    [...]
```

Now I create a table in Trino like this

```
create table hive.qual2.surveys 
(
    id VARCHAR,
    name VARCHAR
)
with (
    format = 'JSON',
    external_location = 's3://test-bucket/surveys'
);
```

`select` data from this table works fine. However, now I also need to know where the information is coming from. So I need to enter a column with e.g a value `abc.json` if the data is coming from this file.

Any clue how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the [docs](https://trino.io/docs/current/connector/hive.html?highlight=hive#metadata-columns) for the hive connector provided by trino, I could just use the `$path` column to see the file where the information is coming from.

to extract the file name without an extension i simply use this:

`split(element_at(split("$path", '/'),-1),'.')[1] as survey_id`

so the whole query looks like this after i created the table as described above.

```
select
  *,
  split(element_at(split("$path", '/'),-1),'.')[1] as survey_id
from hive.qual2.surveys;
```

including `$path` in the create table definition does not make sense, since it already exists as a hidden column.